# References to intimacy between God and the Jewish people

Tags: theology, parashas-yisro, anthropomorphism

There's a [Baal HaTurim on Exodus 19:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Baal_Haturim_on_Exodus.19.4.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> ואביא אתכם אלי מה אשה נקנית בכסף ובשטר **ובביאה** אף ישראל כן. ... בביאה זהו שנא' ואפרוש כנפי עליך וגו' ואבא בברית אתך לכן אמר הושע ג''פ וארשתיך לי: ואביא בגימ' בביאה

I found this quite surprising, as while there are many references to God and Israel being married, I don't recall seeing intimacy referenced before. That's in line with how Chazal generally avoid ascribing such intensely physical things to God, even as an anthropomorphism (e.g. God smells our offerings, but does not taste them).

The Artscroll Baal HaTurim does not say this is based on any prior source. Is there *any* place in which intimacy with the Jewish People is described in Tanach or Chazal?

Comment: I don't think it's referring to actual intimacy. ביאה in the context of marriage is intimacy, but in this context he's just drawing a comparison between this and the wording of the verse (ואביא אתכם אלי)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**WARNING**: THIS ANSWER CAN NOT BE UNREAD. IF YOU THINK HOW YOU RELATE TO A POPULAR *TEFILLAH* AND SONG WILL NEVER RECOVER FROM BEING ANALYZED IN THIS CONTEXT -- SKIP READING THIS!!!!

Aside from Shir haShirim (see [R' Al Berko's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/89254/1570)), there is another example in Tanakh that would more famous -- if people paid more attention to what they're saying in *tefillah*.

Yeshaiah 62:5 is explicit:

> כִּֽי־יִבְעַ֤ל בָּחוּר֙ בְּתוּלָ֔ה, יִבְעָל֖וּךְ בָּנָ֑יִךְ; וּמְשׂ֤וֹשׂ
> חָתָן֙ עַל־כַּלָּ֔ה, יָשִׂ֥ישׂ עָלַ֖יִךְ אֱלֹקיִךְ׃
>
> For as a young man consummates his marriage with a maiden, so shall You consummate your marriage with us; and as a groom rejoices on his bride, so shall your G-d Rejoice upon you.

The "על" in the second half of the verse could have been taken to mean "about", figuratively "over" -- meaning "as a groom rejoices about his bride". But is pretty clear from the context of the first clause talking about בעילה (marital intimacy) that the clause means "on", literally.

From which Rav Shelomo haLevi al-Qabetz (16th cent Tzefat) paraphrases in Lekha Dodi:

> יָשיש עָלַיִךְ אֱלקיִךְ. כִּמְשוש חָתָן עַל כַּלָּה.
>
> Your G-d should rejoice on you the way a groom rejoices on a bride.

Most *siddurim* translate it "rejoice over", with a figurative connotation. Ignoring the scriptural source, or perhaps aware that *siddurim* have younger readers. But given that the author of the poem was one of the leading Qabbalists of Tzefas, erotic imagery is far more likely. And in any case, R Shlomo al-Qabetz's familiarity with the *pasuq* in Yeshaiah is a given.

However, the songwriters who put melodies to this line of Lekha Dodi couldn't possibly be aware of the original in Yeshaiah. Because as a song to sing at weddings, these words are **incredibly** inappropriate.

Comment: Let the downvotes begin!

Comment: וְהָיָה כַּאֲשֶׁר-שָׂשׂ יְהוָה עֲלֵיכֶם, לְהֵיטִיב אֶתְכֶם וּלְהַרְבּוֹת אֶתְכֶם--כֵּן יָשִׂישׂ יְהוָה עֲלֵיכֶם, לְהַאֲבִיד אֶתְכֶם וּלְהַשְׁמִיד אֶתְכֶם; וְנִסַּחְתֶּם מֵעַל הָאֲדָמָה, אֲשֶׁר-אַתָּה בָא-שָׁמָּה לְרִשְׁתָּהּ ?????

Comment: See Radak and TY there, as it is certainly not Peshat in Yeshaya (or anywhere else in tanach), http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Yeshayahu/62.5#e0n7.  Think of "Vayaamod Haam al Moshe", DoubleAA's reference above, and many other places where Al is not literally "on".  However, your comment, "But given that the author of the poem was one of the leading Qabbalists of Tzefas, erotic imagery is far more likely. " is bang-on.  +1.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות My reference isn't just על. It's ישיש על.

Comment: @DoubleAA I realize that, I was just focusing on "Al", though. For the record, there a bunch of other examples of ישיש על that demonstrate that peshat is not like Micha suggests.  Here are some: Devarim 30:9, Yeshaya 32:41, Tzefania 3:17, Tehillim 119:14, 119:162

Comment: @רבותמחשבות My point was that the phrase "yasis alayikh" was here being used as a parallel to "yiv'alukh banayikh". And therefore "al" must be meant literally. Not that it always does mean that. Which implies what Lekha Dodi means by its paraphrase of this clause of the pasuq.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to Yeshaya - but for the first half of the pasuk. (I am definitely not convinced by the inference on the word על, so no need to unread it ☺️.)

Comment: @Arithmomaniac -- since the verse is a poetic doubling, if that's what you think the first part means, that must be what the second part is referring to. And even if you are unconvinced that "al" here is literally "on", it still must be the source/expression of the "sasson" in question.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות - The Targum has such a word-for-word translation, I don't know how you can say the TY is consistent or inconsistent with what I said. Either it applies to "al" in both, or to neither. Radaq speaks of chupah, which in his world refers to yichud. (Being a Sepharadi, weddings in his world don't have a canopy, rather, a shared tallis. And thus they have a machloqes rishonim about whether "chupah" refers to the tallis, or yichud.) But in any case, "be'ilah" is a frequently used word in leshon Chazal; and as I've been saying, the halves of the pesuqim mirror...

Comment: I have another one, but a mitzvah rather than a pasuq. Again, I need to warn off the squeamish before proceeding.

Comment: @MichaBerger I have TY saying וּכְמָא דְחָדֵי חֲתָנָא **עִם** כַּלְתָא יֶחְדֵי עֲלָךְ אֱלָהָיִךְ, which is not word for word, and does not "apply to Al in both".  But credit to you again, you make an excellent point about poetic doubling.  The first part of the Passuk certainly answers the question, I just think the second part actually meaning that may be a bit of a stretch, although I now at least think it is a possibility.  Shkoyach, no need to make others squeamish (although I would like to see which mitzvah you refer to).

Comment: @רבותמחשבות if you want to know privately, email me at micha@aishdas.ptg

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward book is **Shir Hashirim** with all its allegories and interpretations.

Between 3 types of intimacy b/w Hashem and Am Israel (Slaves, Sons, Spouse), this topic is not referenced or discussed by the mainstream (non-Hassidic) Meforshim, as it is very delicate. If you dig deeper in Hassidic and Kabbalic sources, you will find a lot of such allegories and metaphors.

Comment: I was thinking that, but didn't recall anything that specific. Never learned it in depth, though. How deep do you have to dig?

Comment: @Arithmomaniac AriZ"L and his followers explain numerous historical events, especially events sequences by comparing them to different (usually 4) stages of intimacy bw a man and his loved woman as outlined in Halachah, i.g. Shidduch, Kiddushin, Chupah and physical intimacy. THis is especially true for the Exodus also. Many Meforshim that are familiar with those ideas but are not strict followers of Ariz"l's bring fragments here and there.

Comment: Excellent Answer! +1